# A Tricky SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with 2 columns of interest: **ID, Memo_No** plus some other columns.

**ID** is primary key of int type and auto-increment. **Memo_No.** is also int.

I need query, such that if memo no. is occuring only once in the table, the ID associated with it have to be selected.Plus, if same Memo has two different ID's, ID which is greater has to be selected.

For example i have table like this:

---

**ID** ||  **Memo_No**

```
1         2
2         3 
3         4 
4         5 
5         4
6         6
7         2
```

From above table, I want to select rows whose ID's are 2,4,5,6,7 .

Thanks.

Comment: SO is NOT a free code writing service: Please make an attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easy as an aggregation:

```
select max(id), memo_no
from t
group by memo_no;
```

Comment: And, just to prove it! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b226/2 :)